# How to get custom action to a SharePoint list actions menu for a specific list or content type?

Tags: 2010, web-part, custom-actions

I add  custom action to a sharepoint list actios menu for all list .

I want get custom actions that define for a special list in  VS.

How to get custom action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find , I use this code for get custom action of list .:)

```
 SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
 SPList list = web.Lists[MyList];

 SPUserCustomActionCollection actions =list.UserCustomActions;
```

This [link](http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2011/05/13/displaying-the-list-of-custom-actions-and-custom-action-groups/) is useful for me .

Answer (score 3):

To limit the Custom action to a specific type of list you need to specify RegistrationType and RegistrationId like this:

```
<!-- Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu : ActionsMenu : Site Actions menu of document library -->
<CustomAction Id="CustomWareCustomActions.Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu.CustomList.ActionsMenu"
RegistrationType="List"
RegistrationId="101"
GroupId="ActionsMenu"
Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
Sequence="1000"
Title="CUSTOMWARE - Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu : ActionsMenu">
<UrlAction Url="http://www.customware.net/success"/>
</CustomAction>
```

Comment: Thanks, but How do find custom actin of list in code?

Comment: Here is how to access Custom Actions using code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462899/how-do-you-add-custom-menu-actions-programmatically-in-sharepoint